# Memory management (flushing) in LaTeX

Tags: mac, texshop, memory

There are a number of questions here on memory management, but as far as I could see none that quite addresses my problem.

I'm running *TeXShop* under Mac OS 10.12, typesetting an extremely large book.  When I typeset the entire book (nine chapters... each chapter included in the master .tex file) *TeXShop* uses nearly the full memory of my computer.  I cannot open any other programming, graphics, or other large programs simultaneously.  Nevertheless, that is fine. Unavoidable.

Naturally, if I start *TeXShop* and use just `\includeonly{Chapter1}` (say) to typeset one chapter, then the memory usage is much lower and I can open the other graphics, programming and other large programs.  Again, just as expected, and what I need.

The problem arises when I've been typesetting the full book (with no other programs running), and *then* want to open a graphics or other program.  I then use `\includeonly{Chapter1}` and indeed just Chapter 1 is typeset (as expected).  *HOWEVER* the memory usage remains the large value associated with typesetting the full book.  As a result I cannot open the graphics and other programs.

As a kludge, I start fresh:  I quit out of *TeXShop*, re-open the base .tex file and use `\includeonly{Chapter1}` in that file, and typeset just that chapter.  This leads to low memory usage and I can open my additional programs.

But this is a kludge.  Surely after typesetting the full book, then typesetting just Chapter 1 there should be some way to flush the unneeded memory so I can open graphics and other programs.  After all, I'm just seeking an environment equivalent to starting fresh with just Chapter 1.

However, I can find no way to flush the memory, or fully "typeset from scratch" without closing *TeXShop* and starting fresh.

In short:  Is there a way to flush unneeded system memory filled from typesetting a full book when it is no longer needed?

Comment: TeX does not “remember” memory usage between runs, so this has to be some other application (TeXShop, perhaps). Besides, unless you change some memory setting, TeX's maximum allowed memory is a few megabytes (definitely less than 50, which is fine nowadays). Do you have a monitor application which allows you to see _what_ process is taking up so much memory?

Comment: I use *Activity Monitor* on the Mac which shows 1.1 GBytes used by *TeXShop* (and all others are far smaller).

Comment: Hm... quite high. Something's not right... The only reason I can think of for TeXShop to take _that much_ memory is if it loads the entire PDF file into the memory (for preview and such). What's the size of the PDF, in MB (with all the 9 chapters)?

Comment: My book is 530 pages, with many many very large image files included.  Nine chapters:  1.51 GBytes. The full typeset book (pdf):  805Mbytes.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be it. If the entire book takes about that amount of memory, then that may explain the problem: TeXShop is loading the entire PDF file in the memory. However it should free the memory once you compile a single chapter and it updates the PDF. If it does not, I'd consider a bug report...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik please note that for LuaTeX this memory maximum isn't valid as it allocates memory dynamically (still shouldn't be that much).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork do you really need that large images? Keep in mind that in print you'll have the (rather small) resolution of the printer, and there is no zooming in on a printed paper, of course for e-publishing the situation is different.

Comment: Yes... I need such large images.  My book is about fine art paintings.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork will it be printed? Remember that embedding a 2000dpi image doesn't make much sense on a printer capable of 600dpi (your resolutions may vary). But of course art paintings need as much detail as possible, just don't overdo it.

Comment: I'm under contract with a world-leading print publisher.  I suspect the final book will be 800 pages with 1200 figures—some full-page high-resolution images of famous artworks, other margin figures of three-dimensional computer diagrams... and much in-between.  Four-color printing on *every* page.

Comment: As others have commented, this is an issue in TeXshop not TeX itself; borderline for us (as the memory issue in a binary is not something we can advise on). My first thought is to use an alternative editor and see if you can view the PDF with the system PDF application or Adobe Reader.

Comment: a pdf with a size of nearly 1GB (and more before compression) would imho strain every system and pdf viewer. I would suggest that you create smaller versions of your images and use these while writing the book and switch to the real images only in the final phase.

Comment: Maybe you can setup TeXShop in such a way that the preview is disabled, and instead keep an external viewer open to see the pdf? That might give the OS a chance to share the memory more efficiently between TeXShop, the pdf and other programs that you want to run.

Comment: This issue is probably _not_ related to the pdf. I use a TeXShop .engine which uses `-output-directory=`. The .pdf an .aux files are in a separate directory. I open the pdf via Skim. Thus, TeXShop never sees the pdf nor the aux files. Today, I saw that TeXShop memory usage was at 28GB. Since then it dropped and upon restart it is aroung 5GB. I have emailed Richard the details so am hoping it gets looked into. I have seen memory issues since Sierra when Apple switched to their pdfkit. I too had assumed it was related to the pdf, but my experiement show that that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: The above comment is with the lastest version of TeXShop v4.77 on a iMac Pro 2017, 3GHz 10 core, 64GB RAM running macOS 11.4 Big Sur (slightly older OS).